# How to deal with such $\frac{0}{0}$ limitation?

Tags: calculus, matrices

Let $A,B \in R^{n \times n}$ and $v(k) \in R^n$. There exists a time-varying vector $v(k)$ converges to $v \in R^n$, i.e., $\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty } v(k) = v$. And, $v^TA=v^TB=0$, $Av=Bv=0$. Is there any tools to calculate a limit like 
$$ r_{ss} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{v^T(k)Av(k)}{v^T(k)Bv(k)}$$

Actually $v(k)$ is generated from the multiplication of a series of row-stochastic matrix, and $r_{ss}$ always exists through Matlab numerical calculation. What I'm wondering now is how to do the analysis on $r_{ss}$.

Thanks

Exactly, here is a example to show how $v(k)$ converges to $v$:

Let $B=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{3}\\
0
\end{array}\right]$,$L=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right]$,$R=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
I+L & B\\
\mathbf{0} & 1
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$. We have $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}R^{k}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$, and by denoting $B_{d}=diag(B)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{3}\\
 & 0
\end{array}\right]$,$P=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
L^{T}L & L^{T}B\\
B^{T}L & B^{T}B
\end{array}\right]$ , $Q=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
B_{d}{}^{T}B_{d} & B_{d}{}^{T}B\\
B^{T}B_{d} & B^{T}B
\end{array}\right]$, the problem I'd like to look at is 1) the limit process of
the following index 2) the value of $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}r(k)$

$$
r(k)=\frac{y^{T}(0)(R^{T})^{k-1}PR^{k-1}y(0)}{y^{T}(0)(R^{T})^{k-1}QR^{k-1}y(0)}
$$

Comment: Langauge nitpick: What you want is not a "limitation", but a "limit".

Comment: Not that I know if there are no formulas involved in the expressions in your numerator and denominator. Of course one could apply Hospital Rule (provided that it meets the requirement) where k is the variable, but no clue what that result would mean

Comment: Thank yo guys! In fact, $r(k)$ is able to describe how influential a node in a network is in my problem, do you think it's possible to come up with a explicit formula of both numerator and denominator corresponding to $k$ so that I can apply Hospital Rule ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on "how" the $v(k)$ converges to $v$. For example, if the convergence is of the form $v = u + \epsilon$ for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, then the answer will be $\frac{u^TAu}{u^T B u}$ via L'Hopital. Note the dependence of the answer on the vector $u$.

Comment: Thanks, I added a example to show "how" the $v(k)$ converges to $v$ in the problem I concern